# Change the default SDK/tools version for a new project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio generates new projects using SDK version 26. So I have to change that to 27 and add buildToolsVersion "27.0.3", each time. How can I set the defaults to 27?

After searching, I have found that the template is in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root`, but I do not know where to edit.

Perhaps, there is a better way to set those than editing those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deselect SDK version 26 in SDK Manager

> *SDKManager>Android SDK> deselect API level 26 and select API level 27*

Now by default, your SDK version will set to 27 whenever you create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I have a new, improved answer.  With my previous answer, people had to keep updating the version each time.  However, now I figured out a way to never have to update it.  The best way is to delete the "buildToolsVersion ...." line entirely.  That way, Android Studio will always just automatically use the latest version that is out at that point in time.

Here was my OLD answer.  With my NEW answer above, you won't even need to do the steps below ever again:

Android Studio: 
--File > Project Structure > Project SDK > deselect API level 26 and select API level 27
--Tools > SDKManager > Android SDK > deselect API level 26 and select API level 27